# What is the hidden subject of "making" (particple) in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, participles, dangling-participles

What is the subject of "making" in the following sentence? It seems that it is the most reasonable **grammatically** to think "Yakkleman Skin Care" is the hidden subject of making. This is because the subject of the participle needs to agree with the subject of the main clause grammatically.

> Yakkleman Skin Care has signed a deal with NutriSpark Online Shopping, **making** them the only retailer with access to our products.

If "Yakkleman Skin Care has signed a deal with NutriSpark Online Shopping" is the subject of making, "making ---" seems to be a dangling participle. If so, is this kind of usage of participles treated as correct in authoritative English grammar books?

Comment: A purist would probably prefer '... Shopping; this makes them ...' where the transparent referent of the subject 'this' in the second independent clause is the making of the new deal.

Comment: *making them...*  is a reduced “sentence relative clause” (reduced from *which makes them...*. (Warning: grammar terms and frameworks vary.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1: *Yakkleman Skin Care has signed a deal with NutriSpark Online Shopping, making them the only retailer with access to our products*

The "hidden subject" of ***making*** is *[**the fact that**] Yakkleman Skin Care has signed a deal with NutriSpark Online Shopping*. Consider this rephrased version with the same meaning...

> 2: *Yakkleman Skin Care has signed a deal with NutriSpark Online Shopping, **which makes** them the only retailer with access to our products*

...where ***which*** is effectively a "less hidden" *pronoun* referring back to exactly the same "subject".

Comment: Yes. And there’s no dangling going on.

Comment: Well, a "dangling participle" means the "subject" of the participle isn't specified. Where arguably "unspecified" is equivalent to "unknown, indeterminate". And it's only by logically considering which of ***Yakkleman Skin Care*** and ***Yakkleman Skin Care*** is most likely to be a ***retailer*** that we can determine who ***them*** refers to. If it had been ***Company X** has signed a deal with **Company Y**, making them the only retailer with access to our products*, the referent of ***them*** would be ambiguous.

Comment: At the risk of straying too far off topic… I suppose dangling is (somewhat) in the eye of the beholder. Whereas—as OP emphasizes—there is something nonobvious about the sentence’s phrase structure, I expect that its **meaning** is pretty unambiguous. Anyway, that’s what I meant in my previous comment.

Comment: I just noticed I copied the same name twice above. Obviously I meant to say it's pragmatics rather than syntax that enables us to tell whether "the only retailer" refers to ***Yakkleman Skin Care*** or ***NutriSpark Online Shopping***. If they were called ***Company X*** and ***Company Y*** it would be ambiguous which company ***them*** refers to. Come to that, for *all* versions, we can only guess whether ***our*** references one of the named companies at all (it might be that "we" are a completely separate company that supplies "our products" to one of the named companies).